# Layout shiny app to set heights of elements to add up to 100% of window size

Tags: r, shiny

given the default example of an Shiny app, I would like adapt the size of the three plots such that they fill the height of the window. My current output looks like this.

[image]

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fillPage(

# Application title
titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

# Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput("bins",
                    "Number of bins:",
                    min = 1,
                    max = 50,
                    value = 30)
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
        plotOutput("distPlot"),
        plotOutput("distPlot2"),
        plotOutput("distPlot3")
    )
)
)
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
})

output$distPlot2 <- renderPlot({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    
    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
})

output$distPlot3 <- renderPlot({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    
    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
})
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

As you can see from the code, there should be a third plot visible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a height argument to your `plotOutput`s with `30vh` (vertical height, essentially % of container).  You can mess with the value to get it exactly where you want. More info on `vh` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp).

```
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
        plotOutput("distPlot", height = '30vh'),
        plotOutput("distPlot2", height = '30vh'),
        plotOutput("distPlot3", height = '30vh')
    )
```

[image: Output]